# Better understand SSTables Formats big vs bti

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Where can I find more information on which Version of Cassandra supports which version of SSTables.

Recently I noticed DSE Cassandra is generating SSTables **bti**, while Apache Cassandra 3.11.4 continues to generate **big**.

Do you know what is the difference and when would Apache Cassandra start with **bti**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bti` file format is proprietary file format developed by Datastax for DSE 6, so no information about its internals is available. It has a number of optimizations, so, for example, the key cache is not required anymore, etc. Apache Cassandra won't support it until the details of format will be opened by Datastax.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Big Trie is coming to Apache Cassandra 5.9, and bti SSTables will then be available. I know I am answering quite awhile after this question was written, but figured I could add this bit of information.